# My jQuery code does not work in my chat application

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

Is there any problem in my jQuery code? I watched in a tutorial, but in mine it doesn't work. When I click submit, nothing happens.

Do you know what the problem is?

My `view`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var chat_id = "<?php echo $chat_id; ?>" ;
    var user_id = "<?php echo $user_id; ?>" ;
    var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" ;



    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit_message').on('click', function() {
        var chat_message_content = $('#chat_message').val();
        if(chat_message_content == "") { return false; }
        $.post(base_url + "chat/ajax_add_chat_message", { chat_message_content : chat_message_content, chat_id : chat_id, user_id : user_id } , function(data){

            alert(data);

        }, "json");


        return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```

My `controller` (called chat):

```
public function ajax_add_chat_message() {

    $chat_id = $this->input->post('chat_id');
    $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
    $chat_message_content = $this->input->post('chat_message_content');
    $this->load->model('db_chat');
    $this->db_chat->add_chat_message($chat_id , $user_id , $chat_message_content);
}
```

Comment: What doesn't happen? Does the callback get executed? (Do you see the `alert`?) Is there a request and response in your Web browser's developer tools? If so, what's in the response? What do you expect to happen that doesn't happen? Where's the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return something in your ajax_add_chat_message() function to get the alert works :

```
public function ajax_add_chat_message() {

    $chat_id = $this->input->post('chat_id');
    $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
    $chat_message_content = $this->input->post('chat_message_content');
    $this->load->model('db_chat');
    $saved = $this->db_chat->add_chat_message($chat_id , $user_id , $chat_message_content);
    // $saved return TRUE or FALSE

    $response = array('err' => true, 'msg' => 'failed');
    if($saved)
       $response = array('err' => false, 'msg' => 'success');

    return $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')
                        ->set_output(json_encode($response));

}
```

In your View file :

```
$.post(base_url + "chat/ajax_add_chat_message", { chat_message_content : chat_message_content, chat_id : chat_id, user_id : user_id } , function(data){

    alert(data.msg);
    console.log(data);

}, "json");
```